# inclusion map is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

M is smooth manifold.
If $ U \subseteq M $ is an open submanifold with or without boundary, then the inclusion map  $U \hookrightarrow M $ is smooth

My attemp,given $p \in U$,exist $(U_p,\phi) $ and $(V_{i(p)},\psi)$ as smooth chart since $i^{-1}(V_{i(p)})$ is open we have $U_p\bigcap i^{-1}(V_{i(p)}) $ a open set so map $\psi F \phi^{-1} = \psi \phi^{-1}$ is smooth which complete the proof,is my proof correct?

Comment: Yeah, I think you even can show that $\psi F\phi^{-1}=id$ which is a smooth map. You just take a chart $(V_{i(p)},\psi)$, around point $i(p)$, intersect it with U, and pullback via continuous inclusion map and you will obtain a chart $(i^{-1}(U\cap V_{i(p)}),\psi|_U)$ around point $p$ in $U$. So, $\psi \circ i \circ\psi|_U^{-1}=id$ as $i(p)=p$.